# Passing form data back to main view

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter script which loads a fancybox iframe with a form in it to upload images, on close of the fancybox I want to pass the filenames back to the main page...how can I do that? Thanks

```
$('div#fancyBoxLink').click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    overlayOpacity: 0.8,
    overlayColor: '#000',
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 500,
    height: 470,
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    padding: 0,
    href: '<?=base_url();?>admin/news_manager/add_images'
});         
return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method for your news_manager controller get_filenames to retrieve filenames as JSON, for example.
Then write a onClosed event handler for fancybox that will get data by ajax from news_manager/get_filenames and display it on your main page.